# The set of matrices is countable

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\{ M_{n\times m} \mid a_{i, j}\in \Bbb{Z}\ ,  1\le i \le n,1\le j \le m \}$ and $M_{m×n}$ is a matrix. Show that $ A$ is countable. I think in especial case that $M_{2×2} =\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$ we can define the function $f$such that $f: A \to \Bbb{Z×Z×Z×Z}$ and $f\left(\begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix}\right)=(a,b,c,d)$ .it is clear that $f$ is one to one and surjective. Is it true? In general case.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right idea. For any $m,n$, you can define a map which basically just reorders the matrix entries into coordinates in $\mathbb{Z}^{mn}$. As long as you have shown that copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ are countable, then this will work in your general case.